# nautilus will not open as root

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, root

I have reinstalled my ubuntu 11.10 per one accident a couple of days, when I try to open nautilus as root from console I get this error:

```
nautilus[3282]: segfault at 0 ip 00007faa7d56bcea sp 00007faa76aaf928 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[7faa7d4eb000+195000]
```

I un-installed all extensions of the nautilus and the same error still occurs but only as root

My distro is Ubuntu 11.10 64bits

Comment: can you give the steps/command you are using to open nautilus in root mode. Are you using "gksu nautilus"?

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report (software shouldn't crash).  Please could you give more details about exactly how you're starting Nautilus? (Key-combination, menu, something else?).

Comment: I try open from console with "sudo nautilus" and "gksudo nautilus" an the error is the same.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: Thanks but the problem was solved with the latest update of the system

Comment: flagged for closure with permission JoZ3